# How do I authorize separetely from authentication using django-auth-ldap

Tags: django-authentication, django-1.3, django-auth-ldap

I am creating a django application that need to authenticate against our organization's LDAP server which I have successfully done using django-auth-ldap. After authentication, I need to authorize each authenticated user against a local database to check if they have privileges to use the application. How do I go about doing this? I've tried to go through the documentation for django-auth-ldap but cannot find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In you login view I would check the local database and add permissions programmatically after the user has been authenticated, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

```
 if user.is_active:
     login(request, user)
     #your code to query database and add permissions
     _check_and_set_permissions(request)

     return redirect('login_success')
```

If the database you need to check differs from the database you specified for use by the Django ORM

```
 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'NAME': 'DEMODATABASE',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
     }
   }
```

Then just create a connection to the database using your favorite driver/SQL expression language (pymssql, SA, pyMySQLdb, etc.) and query the table containing the permissions you need.